# How to undo Windows server 2012 installation?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I,ve just installed windows server 2012 , after login i can see only cmd . How to get back to previous version (windows 10) ?

Comment: Did you wipe your drive to install Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You installed windows server 2012 and erased the windows 10

- Boot from your Windows 10 installation DVD or USB, or ISO file

  When you see Windows Setup, press the Shift + F10 keys.

  Click/tap on Repair your computer